# Obtain separate exports from individual modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

In `modules.js` I have this code:

```
module.exports = {
    BookingHotel: function() {
        this.getId = function(id) {
            return "Hello World";
        },

        this.getAll = function() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    },

    BookingFlight: function() {
        this.book = function() {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    },    
}
```

The `modules.js` file is becoming too large and difficult to maintain.

How do I separate `BookingHotel` and `BookingFlight` into separate files and export them like they currently are?

Comment: Remove either `BookingHotel` or `BookingFlight` and put it in a new file. Follow the exact same pattern you did this file. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make separate files for the objects:
   `BookingHotel.js`
   `BookingFlight.js`
2. Export the objects from their respective files:

BookingHotel.js:

```
export default var BookingHotel = function() {
    this.getId = function(id) {
        return "Hello World";
    },

    this.getAll = function() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

BookingFlight.js:

```
export default var BookingFlight = function() {
    this.book = function() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

3. Then import them in the `modules.js` file and add them to the exports object:

modules.js:

```
import BookingHotel from 'BookingHotel.js';
import BookingFlight from 'BookingFlight.js';

module.exports = {
    BookingHotel: BookingHotel,
    BookingFlight: BookingFlight
};
```

Comment: The most confusing part of this answer is why are you mixing ES module and CommonJS syntax?

Comment: Do you mean the `function` declaration for anonymous functions, or perhaps the use of objects instead of classes? If that's what you mean, it's because the person who asked the question used it, and I wanted it to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate JavaScript file for each export in `modules.js` and have each file export one function, then just require each file and re-export the functions like this:

**NOTE**: The names of the individual files don't matter as long as they're consistent with the filenames used in `modules.js`.

BookingHotel.js:

```
module.exports = {
    BookingHotel: function() {
        // Your code here
    }
};
```

BookingFlight.js:

```
module.exports = {
    BookingFlight: function() {
        // Your code here
    }
};
```

modules.js:

```
// Get the exports from BookingHotel.js
var BookingHotelExports = require("./BookingHotel.js");
// Get the exports from BookingFlight.js
var BookingFlightExports = require("./BookingFlight.js");
// Combine the individual exports from the two required modules into a new exports variable for this module.
module.exports = {
    // BookingHotel is a property of the module.exports object from BookingHotel.js.
    BookingHotel: BookingHotelExports.BookingHotel,
    // Same here, but from BookingFlight.js.
    BookingFlight: BookingFlightExports.BookingFlight
};
```

Comment: `modules.js` could be written as `const { BookingHotel } = require('./BookingHotel.js');
const { BookingFlight } = require('./BookingFlight.js');

module.exports = {
    BookingHotel, BookingFlight
};`